# Suggestions for allowing basic users to view their own posts?

Tags: user-access, membership, page-specific-settings

I have a client that needs to give access to her clients certain documents. She wants the ability to give them user name and password, so once they log in, they go directly to their page or post which will list the documents available for download. Plugins don't seem to help here and some are way too complicated. I have read many articles and tried several concepts but can't get it right. It's almost a membership to access info, but it's free and members can only be allowed to see what was written for them.

This is a tough one for me. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in short, I had our in-house programmer build me a 3rd party system which we integrated into Wordpress. WP is awesome, but not quite there yet with these kinds of features built in. To the future!

Answer (score 0):

give my plugin a try [**User Specific Content**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-specific-content/)